# Is there a way to send usb camera stream through a color filter before it gets to Zoom or similar?

Tags: video, video-editor, video-streaming, zoom-meeting

Pretty much I wanted to see if there was a way to adjust color settings before it gets to a streaming app.

Thanks!!

Comment: Some cameras drivers allow you to adjust colour capturing and filtering on the "device-level" itself. I assume there are apps for this as well, but it would really help us if you state your OS version and flavor first.

Comment: Oh @Pizza ideally for the latest version of Ubuntu, or I guess even if there was like a filter pedal for audio, but for video instead.